# JQuery instruction can't toggle class on only one target

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I'm running a quit mysterious error today on one of my JQuery script.
I've got a simple HTML page like this:

```
<section id="article" class="col-xs col-md col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <nav id="page_menu">
        <ol>
            <li class="page_menu_selected"><a href="#9">Community</a></li>
            <li class="page_menu_unselected"><a href="#42">irc channels</a></li>
            <li class="page_menu_unselected"><a href="#40">mailing lists</a></li>
            <li class="page_menu_unselected"><a href="#38">q&amp;a section</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <article class="show" id="9">
    <h3>TITLE:</h3>
        <p>Blablablba 01</p>
    </article>
    <article class="hidden" id="42"></article>
    <article class="hidden" id="40"></article>
    <article class="hidden" id="38">
        <h3>TITLE:</h3>
            <p>BLABLABLABLA 02</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

and the JQuery associated script:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $( "li.page_menu_unselected" ).click(
        function(){
            $("li.page_menu_selected").toggleClass("page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected")
            $( this ).toggleClass("page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected");
    });
});
```

at first glance, when I started to test my code, it seems everything is OK as I click on unselected element and the class toggle correctly, even the one which has selected class value.

This list item element which have the initial "selected" class value is the list with the link id 9.

The problem is when I click back on this list element, it do not switch back to its initial class unkike all other list items.

If I try to push my pasted code on the chrome console once the page is loaded and try to use it, TADA it work like a charm!

I think it's a DOM issue but can't figure it out where it is.

Comment: Tip: Avoid `ids` starting with a number. It's not recommended.

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon in your code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK just a copy/paste issue ;-) but thx for your answer about ids with numbers, unfortunatly, I have to use them as the page is partly generated by Wordpress :D

Comment: On this same `script` block you can loop through these elements and _fix_ their `ids` by prefixing them with some `string` value.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, no I can't as the id is returned by the wordpress function and come from a specific page that do not have any text reference but an id and/or menu_order int value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `delegation` here, as your first item won't have the click event handler attached to it on the first load (its `class` - `page_menu_selected` - is different from the one used in the `jQuery` selector - `page_menu_unselected`).

Using `delegation` you'll guarantee any future elements added to the `DOM` that fits in the `jQuery` selector will be selected the same way:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'li.page_menu_unselected', function () {                 
        $('li.page_menu_selected').toggleClass('page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/drtuqbjj/)

[jQuery .on() - Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Arff... I feel so dumb right now as the answer is so obvious and logic...
That explain why my copy/paste/action is working as it scan the whole DOM again and that time the first item already have the proper value.
Thanks a lot to pointing out my error.
Oh and thanks about the .on() delegation function, I'll use it as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is when the page loads, its finding all `li.page_menu_unselected` at once, and then attaching the event to them. When those classes change, the attached event logger fails, because its not there anymore. Using `delegate()` will fix that.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(document).delegate("li.page_menu_unselected", "click", function(){
        $("li.page_menu_selected").toggleClass("page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected")
        $( this ).toggleClass("page_menu_unselected page_menu_selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery `delegated` is deprecated, use `on` with jQuery 1.7+

Comment: While it's not officially deprecated, delegate() has been superseded by the on() method since 1.7.